# Is it enough to cover the drawings and pictures or should we get rid of it completely?

Tags: halal-haram, image

As you know, we shouldn't keep any pictures in our houses because the Angels do not enter. My question is, is it enough to just cover these pictures with for example tapes or bags or even flip it upside down so it's hidden or do we have to completely throw it outside the house. Because you know almost every product today has some sort of pictures of either male, female or kids like shampoos or even cereals. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's enough to cover them as there is a hadith supporting this

[image]

https://sunnah.com/bukhari/46/40